# Nextflow version 0.26 Installation

Tags: installation, nextflow

I'm trying to run a Nextflow-based pipeline, but I receive this message:
"This workflow requires Nextflow version 0.26 or greater -- You are running version 20.01.0"

I have tried two commands to install Nextflow on my system:
wget -qO- https://get.nextflow.io | bash
AND
curl -fsSL get.nextflow.io | bash

Both of them install version 20.01.0. What should I do to get  version 0.26?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

If you already have Nextflow installed, you can use the `NXF_VER` [environment variable](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/config.html#environment-variables) to specify which version of Nextflow to run:

```
NXF_VER=0.26.0 nextflow run ...
```

Alternatively, install the release you want using:

```
wget -qO- https://github.com/nextflow-io/nextflow/releases/download/v0.26.0/nextflow-0.26.0-all | bash
```